# mysql memory table can not grow bigger than 2G in size

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have set `max_heap_table_size` to 5G (5368709120), but my memory table can not grow further than 2G in size. Mysql process is 64 bit, so it has plenty of memory and also there is physical memory available. But despite that fact I got an error `ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 1: The table 'my_cache' is full`

There is size growth over time:

```
data_mb index_mb total
2048.00 1178.28 3226.28
2048.00 984.57  3032.57
2048.00 792.84  2840.84
1795.40 599.13  2394.53
1218.23 407.41  1625.64
665.04  221.68  886.71
```

What is wrong?

**UPD** I increased `max_heap_table_size` to `10G` and it worked and there was no error!

Growth stats:

```
2048.00 1563.72 3611.72
2048.00 1370.00 3418.00
2048.00 1178.28 3226.28
2048.00 984.57  3032.57
2048.00 792.84  2840.84
1795.40 599.13  2394.53
```

What happened?

Comment: No idea if that is relevant, but did you restart the server after setting the value?

Comment: @juergend, no, I ll try

Comment: @juergend, same issue even after restart with `max_heap_table_size` configured in `my.ini`, however I increased amount to `10G` and it worked, total table size (data + index) increased to `3611.72 MB` only

Comment: You could try this with MariaDB instead of MySQL (100% backward compatible). It seems to accept row_format=compressed. Then your data might fit in the 5GB limit.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, unfortunately I am not the guy who selects what db to use, so even if mariadb works, that will not be possibe to switch to it. I solved this problem by reducing `my_cache` table size so it will not exceed limits.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `show variables like 'max_heap_table_size'` to check the size limit.
2. Then `set  max_heap_table_size=xxxxxxx;`
3. Truncate the table and issue Alter table on it to make the value effective for this table.`truncate table table_name;`,`alter table table_name ENGINE=MEMORY;`
4. Better to change the max_heap_table_size value in mysql config file, avoid the changes dismiss after mysql service restart.

Answer (score 0):

> - MEMORY tables are never converted to disk tables. To ensure that you don’t accidentally do anything foolish, you can set the
>     max_heap_table_size system variable to impose a maximum size on MEMORY
>     tables. For individual tables, you can also specify a MAX_ROWS table
>     option in the CREATE TABLE statement

[What says percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/)
[Here is an example](http://www.mysqlplus.net/tag/max_heap_table_size/)